# Samsung S4 - Default browser not loading webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, samsung-mobile

We have developed a webpage which uses ssl hence https:// and it loads fine on all (*the ones we have tested so far) just fine...

however when attempting to load on the Samsung Galaxy S4 - it just shows "This web page is not available"

This is Samungs default browser (which apparently when conducting browser checks still shows as Chrome 18) - loading the site on the chrome browser (which comes installed by default) works fine.

So the question is what do we need to do for the device to load the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you freshly installed SSL for that website?

When you install a SSL on your website (static IP from the server changes to the new IP in which you have installed SSL) So just wait for 24-48 hrs(Max) as it needs to propagate in all the dns servers. It is also a good idea in such cases to clear up your browser’s cache and try visiting your website

Comment: check the above answer.